# Rebuild Docker container service after local changes in service code

Tags: docker

My docker-compose.yml looks as follows:

```
services:
  application:
    entrypoint: [bin/start]
    image: myimage:release-v5
    env_file: .env
    ...
```

Recreate the container for that service as follows:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build application
docker-compose restart
```

The problem is that, my local changes don't seem to be there at all, no changes after container service has been deployed!

What am I missing ?

Comment: Is there a `build:` block in the `docker-compose.yml` file?  Are you using `volumes:` to override the image's content with something else?

Comment: No build block are in my docker-compose.yml .No i don’t use any volume for that. My thought was after recreating the container it will have the changes in application, but it’s not the case 

Comment: Still here ? i have not fix the problem ...

Comment: If you haven't done anything to rebuild the image, then restarting the container will have the exact same code as before.

Comment: here i recreated the container successfully:`docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build application`. The problem is that the changes in application could not be reflected after rebuild. Ist docker not building from the given service code path ?

Comment: Nothing you've shown is rebuilding the _image_.  You're creating a new _container_, but it's based on the same image as before, with the same source code built into the image.

Comment: Really, should i have run `docker-compose build --no-cache` for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the update problem, I did the modifications **in the container itself** using the **vi-command** *not in outside of it*.

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash
```

and then I exited the container. Lastly I just restarted the container and my changes were there now:

```
docker restart <CONTAINER_ID>
```

But I'm still not happy with this way of doing it.

(`<CONTAINER_ID>` is hereby the CONTAINER ID as returned by `docker ps` or `docker ps -a`).